# Filling out checkboxes and comboboxes via WebClient

Tags: c#, combobox, web-scraping, radio-button, webclient

I'm writing code that logs into a website using WebClient credentials then fills out a a few data fields using a NameValueCollection which looks something like this-

```
    //getting details to log in
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Pas$word");

//Getting the details for the datafields
           NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("TextInput1", "Input here");
            values.Add("TextInput2", "Input here");
            values.Add("TextInput3", "Input here");
            values.Add("TextInput4", "Input here");
            //combobox doesnt work\/
            values.Add("Combobox1", "Input here");
            //combo doesnt work\/
            values.Add("Combobox2", "Input here");
            values.Add("TextInput5", "Input here");
            values.Add("TextInput6", "Input here");
            values.Add("Checkbox1", "checked");
            //selectbox doesnt work\/
            values.Add("IBCombobox31ACC", "Input here");
            //Radio Buttons weird
            values.Add("RadioButton1", "checked");

            using (client)
            {

                byte[] result = client.UploadValues("https://www.websitename.com", "POST", values);
                string ResultAuthTicket = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                Console.WriteLine(ResultAuthTicket);
            }
```

So after the code fills the data fields and posts the webpage it should return a resulting page with some important information on it, however its just returning the same page with all the data boxes filled out except for the comboboxes and radio button which stay set to the default.

Is there anyway to make the namevaluecollection fill out a combobox and check a radio button? or is there a better method to filling out and posting a webform which has comboboxes and radiobuttons and also which requires web credentials?